# Google ML Engine - Internal Server Error before run of second trial

Tags: google-cloud-ml-engine

I am attempting to run a hyper-parameter tuning job on the Google ML Engine, but I seem to have an error whenever I do more than 1 trail within the same job.  I get the following error message: `Internal error occurred. Please retry in a few minutes. If you still experience errors, contact Cloud ML.` with the job log showing the following:

- [Job log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNWf4.png)
- [Internal Error JSON log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yh8j.png)

I've been trying to run the same job since Friday but to no avail.

Comment: Hi I got this error without even starting my new ML job. So it wasn't even loading the job !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your hyperparameters have exactly one possible value, so the first Hyperparameter trial exhausted the parameter space and there wasn't anything new to try for a second trial.

Of course, this should not be communicated as an Internal Error, so I'll make sure that gets fixed.

Comment: Hi so is that something to do with our scripts ? I actually tried a new job , It's still failed in the preparing stage .